# PHP generated content divs auto expand to fit wrapper div width

Tags: php, html, css

I am using PHP to generate divs containing text which I fit in a wrapper div with a fixed width

Generated HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- PHP generated divs -->
  <div class="element">Home</div>
  <div class="element">Items</div>
  <div class="element">About</div>
  <div class="element">FAQ</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.element {
  height: inherited;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to have the four elements stretch within the boundaries of the wrapper div so they all have an equal width of 150px. If the PHP generates 6 divs then their width should be 100px. I just want them to be evenly spaced within the wrapper.

The whole problem origins from the unknown number of element divs because they are generated through php. Their count is variable so I have no way to predict this in the css, that's why I can't put a fixed width on an element div.

Is there any CSS solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating it with PHP why not simply add a specific class to them with the number of elements and keep a list of CSS classes with the different widths (needed for cross browser)?

E.g.:

```
$menu = array('Home', 'Items', 'About', 'FAQ');
$count = count($menu);
foreach($menu as $item) {
    echo '<div class="element_'.$count.'">'.$item.'</div>';
}
```

CSS

```
.element_4 { width: 150px; }
.element_6 { width: 100px; }
```

Comment: Thnaks, that's a nice workaround, although this means that if I change  the fixed width of the wrapper element to 800, it won't work anymore because I have to restyle the whole css holding the element_* classes.

Comment: As a fix for this you can change the fixed width to a width using percentages. Although that might be hard to calculate with some number.

Answer (score 1):

If it is OK for you to support Internet Explorer only 8 and higher (Firefox, Chrome and Safari are of course included) I would suggest to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` like I've shown in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/Dg4sz/

Otherwise you will need to mess with `display: inline-block` and `zoom: 1` hacks for old IE

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be something similar to table but I haven't been playing with CSS for quite a while. This works exactly as I want it! I have a separate sheet for ie versions before 8 so I don't mind that it does not work for those versions.